# Accessing result of a golang yacc generated parser

Tags: parsing, go, yacc

I am trying to create a parser using [golang's yacc tool](https://golang.org/cmd/yacc/). I found [nex](https://github.com/blynn/nex) to simplify creating a lexer to give the parser. My problem now is that the generated parser has no method or field to give me access to the parsing result. I could just store the parse result in a global variable, but that seems wrong.

Currently I've added the following as an initial attempt to the top of my parser.y file:

```
type ResultParser interface {
  yyParser // Generated parser interface
  Result() s.Expr // s.Expr is an interface for the parsed result
}

func (p *yyParserImpl) Result() s.Expr {
  return p.stack[1].expr
}

func NewResultParser() ResultParser {
  return &yyParserImpl{}
}
```

**Is there a recomended/better way of getting at the result from the parser?**
(Since this feels like a bit of an abuse of the generator...)

Comment: What do you mean by parse result?

Comment: When parsing the input I build a tree structure. It is stored in the `$$.expr`. I want to get the root of that tree. The above `Result` function seem to access the right result, but it feels a bit hacky. I'm not 100% sure that `p.stack[1]` will be where the root/parse result is always stored...

Comment: Yeah, don't grovel in yacc's undocumented data structures, I suppose. I guess it's either "global variables" or "fields of the yyLexer interface's underlying type"; I use the latter

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the better approach. The above also breaks if I use another prefix so it's not very robust. I just wrote my own lexer anyway so, while it doesn't feel like the right place to store the result it's a lot better than a global variable. Just noticed that the parser also has a global `yyErrorMessages` variable :\ hmm..

Answer (score 6):

No, accessing `stack[1]` does not work reliably. It doesn’t contain any result as soon as the stack needs to grow beyond 16, its initial size. (See [#16163](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16163).)

The `if` statement after the `yystack` label then creates a new stack and totally forgets about the one saved in `yyParserImpl`.

---

I did the following.

Add a `result` field to the lexer type:

```
type ShellLexer struct {
    /* … */
    result *ShellProgram
}
```

Extend the grammar by the following rule at the very beginning:

```
start : program {
    shyylex.(*ShellLexer).result = $$
}
```

(This depends on the parameter name of the `Parse` method (which can have a custom prefix), but I think that’s ok.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: use sed to insert additional field into the generated parser. Then, in your grammar action, assign the value.

```
go tool yacc -o parser.go -p Filter parser.y
sed -i '/type FilterParserImpl struct/a tree *treeNode' parser.go
```

The generated parser:

```
type FilterParserImpl struct {
tree *treeNode
    lval  FilterSymType
    stack [FilterInitialStackSize]FilterSymType
    char  int
}
```

Grammar action:

```
filter { Filterrcvr.tree = $1 }
```